Spring security SMAL2 provider doesn't allow to accept a SAML response unsigned
I have implemented SAML2 using spring security. I observed that, it is not allowed to consume a SAML response unsigned.
I observed that, It is not allowed to consume  UNSIGNED SAML response coming from asserting party. Error I am getting says that at least asserting or full document or both should be signed.
I believe that for the same reason, it is not allowing me to create a RelyingPartyRegistration from asserting party metadata, which do not have a KeyDescriptor.
Question : Is it a intended behavior or a issue with spring security?
